# Unable to create a thrust device vector

Tags: cuda, thrust

So I'm trying to start on GPU programming and using the Thrust library to simplify things.
I have created a test program to work with it and see how it works, however whenever I try to create a thrust::device_vector with non-zero size the program crashes with "Run-time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'result' is being used without being initialized.' (this comes from the allocator_traits.inl file) And... I have no idea how to fix this.
The following is all that is needed to cause this error.

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

int main()
{
    int N = 100;
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_a(N);
    return 0;
}
```

I suspect it may be a problem with how the environment is set up so the details on that are...
Created using visual studio 2019, in a CUDA 11.0 Runtime project (the example program given when opening this project works fine, however), Thrust version 1.9, and the given GPU is a GTX 970.

Comment: What happens if you change to `{ thrust::device_vector<int> d_a(N); }`

Comment: are you building a debug project?  Try switching to a release project.  If this is a problem for you, I recommend filing a bug at developer.nvidia.com using the instructions [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-to-report-a-bug/67911).  FWIW, as a simple test I was able to click "Ignore" on the dialog, and otherwise run/debug a CUDA program.  You may also get a dialog at the end of execution, which you can click Ignore also.  This seems to only manifest in debug project.  (And only with CUDA 11, perhaps.  I was not able to reproduce the issue with CUDA 10.1)

Comment: Switching to release or ignoring the popups worked. I wasn't expecting the program to continue afterwards just fine but that makes a bit of sense given it's specified as a debug error. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This issue only seems to manifest with the thrust version (1.9.x) associated with CUDA 11.0, and only in debug projects on windows/Visual Studio.

Some workarounds would be to switch to building a release project, or just click "Ignore" on the dialogs that appear at runtime.  According to my testing this allows ordinary run or debug at that point.

I have not confirmed it, but I believe this issue is fixed in the latest [thrust](https://github.com/thrust/thrust) (1.10.x) just released (although not part of any formal CUDA release at this moment, I would expect it to be part of some future CUDA release).

Answer (score 1):

Following the Answer of Robert Crovella, I fixed this issue by changing the corresponding lines of code in the thrust library with the code from GitHub. More precisely, in the file **...\CUDA\v11.1\include\thrust\detail\allocator\allocator_traits.inl** I replaced the following function

```
template<typename Alloc>
__host__ __device__
  typename disable_if<
    has_member_system<Alloc>::value,
    typename allocator_system<Alloc>::type
  >::type
    system(Alloc &)
{
  // return a copy of a default-constructed system
  typename allocator_system<Alloc>::type result;
  return result;
}
```

by

```
template<typename Alloc>
__host__ __device__
  typename disable_if<
    has_member_system<Alloc>::value,
    typename allocator_system<Alloc>::type
  >::type
    system(Alloc &)
{
  // return a copy of a default-constructed system
  return typename allocator_system<Alloc>::type();
}
```