# How to fix thrust error when initializing device_vector "The variable 'result' is being used without being initialized"

Tags: c++, thrust

I am trying to learn how to use C++ Thrust.
I am trying to run the vectors example from Nvidia's documentation [found here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/index.html#vectors).
when I try to run it I get the following runtime error:

```
Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'result' is being used without being initialized. occurred
```

the error originates from internal CUDA code but when debugging I found that the offending line is:

```cpp
thrust::device_vector<int> D = H;
```

Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

EDIT: the error occurs in an internal CUDA file called `allocator_traits.inl` line 350 `return result;`

the relevant code block:

```cpp
template<typename Alloc>
__host__ __device__
  typename disable_if<
    has_member_system<Alloc>::value,
    typename allocator_system<Alloc>::type
  >::type
    system(Alloc &)
{
  // return a copy of a default-constructed system
  typename allocator_system<Alloc>::type result;
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you show more context for that code snippet please?  In particular, it doesn't mention `result` anywhere.

Comment: @Paul Sanders I have edited the question

Comment: OK, thanks.  It's hard to know exactly what's going on, with it being a template and all, but there's no explicit initialisation of `result` in that code.  But from the comment there, it's supposed to be a class (or struct) with a default constructor.  Can you walk through it in a debugger to see exactly what `typename allocator_system<Alloc>::type result` does?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63888117/unable-to-create-a-thrust-device-vector